# (Flutter) pub get failed chat depends on charts_flutter >=0.0.1+1 <0.4.0 which requires SDK version >=1.23.0 <2.0.0 exit code 1

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hello everyone and happy new year.

I am a beginner with flutter and dart an I have an issue on flutter whenever I add `charts_flutter` in my **pubspec.yaml** dependencies.

I tried running `flutter clean`, look out for the others topics with this kind of issue, and changed the Flutter SDK environment but it didn't work.

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
   final String title;
   @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class ClicksPerYear {
   final String year;
   final int clicks;
   final charts.Color color;
   ClicksPerYear(this.year, this.clicks, Color color)
      : this.color = new charts.Color(r: color.red, g: color.green, b: color.blue, a: color.alpha);
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   int _counter = 0;
   void _incrementCounter() {
   setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   var data = [
   new ClicksPerYear('2016', 12, Colors.red),
   new ClicksPerYear('2017', 42, Colors.yellow),
   new ClicksPerYear('2018', _counter, Colors.green),
    ];
   var series = [
   new charts.Series(
        domainFn: (ClicksPerYear clickData, _) => clickData.year,
        measureFn: (ClicksPerYear clickData, _) => clickData.clicks,
        colorFn: (ClicksPerYear clickData, _) => clickData.color,
        id: 'Clicks',
        data: data,
      ),
    ];
   var chart = new charts.BarChart<ClicksPerYear>(
      series,
      animate: true,
    );
   var chartWidget = new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
      child: new SizedBox(
        height: 200.0,
        child: chart,
      ),
    );
   return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
   new Text('You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
   new Text('$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            chartWidget,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  charts_flutter: ^0.2.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

And these are the error messages:

> Running "flutter pub get" in chat...
>   The current Dart SDK version is 2.8.0-dev.0.0.flutter-aa6709974d.
>   Because chat depends on charts_flutter >=0.0.1+1 <0.4.0 which requires SDK version >=1.23.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
>   pub get failed (1; Because chat depends on charts_flutter >=0.0.1+1 <0.4.0 which requires SDK version >=1.23.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.)
>   exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

**What went wrong?**

You are adding an outdated version of the [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter#-installing-tab-) plugin which relies on an older version of the Flutter SDK.

**What can you do?**

In your **pubspec.yaml**, replace:

```xml
charts_flutter: ^0.2.0
```

With

```
charts_flutter: ^0.8.1
```

**Why am I encountering this issue?**

> Because chat depends on charts_flutter >=0.0.1+1 <0.4.0 which requires SDK version >=1.23.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed. pub get failed (1; Because chat depends on charts_flutter >=0.0.1+1 <0.4.0 which requires SDK version >=1.23.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.) exit code 1

As seen in the logs, charts_flutter `v0.2.0` requires Flutter SDK `>=1.23.0 <2.0.0`. In your case, it's currently using Flutter SDK version `>=2.1.0 <3.0.0`.

**pubspec.yaml**

```xml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `flutter upgrade` in your terminal to upgrade `flutter` to the latest stable version. You can read this [upgrading flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading)